# What sort of cap should I use for antenna connector?

Tags: wifi, hardware, compute-module, compute-module-4

I plan to use CM4 with a Wi-Fi/Bluetooth antenna. The antenna will be detachable from housing of the designed product. What sort of a cap should I use? Options are shorting and non-shorting.

Edit:
CM4 has a U.FL connector, official CM4 antenna kit comes in two parts ([look it up here](https://raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4-antenna-kit)). There is a panel mount SMA connector. Question is simple: should a shorting or a non-shorting SMA cap be used during transport of the device?

Shorting cap looks like [that](https://amphenolrf.com/132331.html) Non-shorting has no pin in the middle.

I did look at the docs for CM4, and even at the docs of the RF module, but there seems to be no info on that particular aspect of the design.